# new SimpleXMLElement French Character Error

Tags: xml

I used new SimpleXMLElement to convert a xml string to xml, it contains the French characters.  After conversion, the French characters changed. For example,  "DÃ©placement pour participer Ã  la confÃ©rence de".

The code is the following:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
$xmlStringContents, 0, false);

... 

foreach($xml->PRODUCTS->PRODUCT as $key => $value){ 
     foreach ($value as $key => $value){
      $sourceArray[$key]=htmlspecialchars((String)$value, ENT_QUOTES);
      debug('value is '. htmlspecialchars((String)$value, ENT_QUOTES));

 }
```

Can anybody help with it? Thank you!

Comment: Does anybody have the solution?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem with my XML file.  It should be saved to UTF-8.